# Should "pity up-votes" be discouraged?

Tags: discussion

I regularly see people up-vote questions that are about to get closed. Usually the question is an obvious duplicate or a "where to get started" question. I think it's a good idea to try to set the OP straight in the comments and get them pointed to the help they need. Also, if I can see that the OP is really trying to create a good question (albeit off topic) or apologetic about their mistake, I can see not down voting. But wouldn't up voting such a question only give people the wrong idea? Should we discourage people from up voting questions that are "bad"?

Examples:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32589/first-programming-language-c

[Easiest way to create a 2d game in Java?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32565/easiest-way-to-create-a-2d-game-in-java)

Comment: Secondary question: "How should 'pity upvotes' be discouraged?"

Comment: I suppose just by asking. But that's a good question, since it's not clear who up votes.

Comment: For every pity upvote there's a knee-jerk down vote that needs to be countered sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0) It has already been discussed here [Almost every question get's at least one up, even if they are bad](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/492/almost-every-question-gets-at-least-one-up-even-if-they-are-bad)

1) It may or may not be a systemic issue: [Is there an actual "pity" or "sympathy" upvote problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93356/is-there-an-actual-pity-or-sympathy-upvote-problem)

2) The opinions all over the place [Towards Preventing "Pity Up Votes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42689/towards-preventing-pity-up-votes)

Opinions regarding "Is pity-voting a problem?" from that thread:

- "Yes it's a problem, and the problem is that a pity upvote counteracts 10 downvotes. We should rebalance the score, either by making downvotes more punishing or by making upvotes on negative scores less rewarding"
- "No; I upvote a -5 question because it's actually a -2 question"
- "No; I want to encourage a new user to participate. The negative score is enough to indicate an issue"
- "Mu; People will vote how they will"

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, I looked around gamedev meta, but not the main SE. Oops. This is as answered as it's going to get in those threads. Thanks for looking into that.